GSPREAD bulk export of dataframes on separate sheets without triggering API write request limits
I am running up against the gsheet api quota for write requests when writing some relatively small dataframes to a single spreadsheet.
The dataframes are held in a dictionary.  The KEY is used for the SHEET name and the VALUE is the dataframe to be exported.
Right now I'm running through the dataframes in a loop, creating the SHEET and saving the data.
gc = gspread.oauth(credentials_filename=credential_path("credentials.json"),
                   authorized_user_filename=credential_path("token.json")
                   )

gc_sh = gc.create('rote_output_' + yyyymmddhhss())


# (rote_data is the dictionary of dataframes)
for k, v in rote_data.items():
    gc_sh.add_worksheet(title=k, rows=100, cols=20)
    worksheet = gc_sh.worksheet(k)
    worksheet.update([v.columns.values.tolist()] + (v.fillna('')).values.tolist())
    worksheet.freeze(rows=1)

It feels like the four 'operations' in the loop are being treated as separate calls and as such, if I have 15 dataframes, I hit 60 write requests instantly, triggering the api block.
Is there a way to conduct the updates as a 'bulk' request so as not to hit these limits?  The batch_update() documentation is light on detail and I'm not sure that it is possible to create and then save down to different sheets using this formula, which would be ideal.
** EDIT:
How to create multiple sheets in a spreadsheet by gspread and python?
From this question/answer it appears that batch_update might be able to do this although it's not clear how I would combine the request to create a sheet, with the actual updating of the data on each sheet
client =  # Please use your client.

employee_names = ["Jonny", "Emma",,,] # Please set the sheet names. spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your spreadsheet ID.

requests = [
    {
        "addSheet": {
            "properties": {
                "title": e,
                "gridProperties": {"rowCount": 100, "columnCount": 20},
            }
        }
    }
    for e in employee_names ]  
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})


I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to create a new Google Spreadsheet.
You want to create 60 sheets in the new Spreadsheet. Each sheet has 100 rows and 20 columns and you want to freeze the 1st row in each sheet.
You want to put the values rote_data to each sheet.
You want to reduce the process cost.

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
gc_sh = gc.create('rote_output_' + yyyymmddhhss())

# --- I modified the below script.
# Create request bodies.
request1 = []
request2 = []
for k, v in rote_data.items():
    request1.append({"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": k, "gridProperties": {"rowCount": 100, "columnCount": 20, "frozenRowCount": 1}}}})
    request2.append({"range": f"'{k}'!A1", "values": [v.columns.values.tolist()] + (v.fillna('')).values.tolist()})

# Use Sheets API.
gc_sh.batch_update({"requests": request1})
gc_sh.values_batch_update({"data": request2, "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"})


In this modification, 2 sheet APIs are used with request1 and request2. At first request, new sheets are inserted. And, at the second request, the values are put into each sheet.

Note:

In the case of Sheets API, when Method: spreadsheets.create is used, gc_sh = gc.create('rote_output_' + yyyymmddhhss()) and gc_sh.batch_update({"requests": request1}) can be merged by one API call. But, in the current stage, it seems that gspread has no method for using "Method: spreadsheets.create". So, I proposed the above modification.
I couldn't know your actual values of rote_data. So, in order to use "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED", I used values_batch_update.

References:

batch_update
values_batch_update


Dude.  That's magnificent.  Worked first time.   I just couldn't have done this from the documentation alone!

@lb_so Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
